# Spring : Migrating to OpenJDK-10 not working, mvn install is working

Tags: java, spring, maven, jetty

I am working on a Spring-MVC project, where I am currently trying to migrate to OpenJDK 10. I am able to do a mvn clean install, but when I run the project, it's not working out. I get errors about Pricing.class, Eventlist.class, which are not even part of my project. I am trying to run the project in Jetty-9.4. I have already excluded jetty.annotations from dependency tree, but no luck. I am not even sure that's the error causing this problem.

Error log :

```
2019-02-19 14:07:56.349:INFO:oeja.AnnotationConfiguration:Scanner-1: Scanning elapsed time=3702ms
2019-02-19 14:07:56.350:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:Scanner-1: Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@1db58d85{/,file:///home/akshay/Downloads/twentynotes/target/TOOLTANK/,UNAVAILABLE}
MultiException[java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file Webhook.class, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file Money.class, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file EventList.class, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file CheckoutList.class, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file Addresses.class, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file Checkout.class, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file Pagination.class, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file Event.class, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file Charge.class, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file RequestResponseLoggingInterceptor.class, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file Payment.class, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file ChargeTimeline.class, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file ChargeList.class, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file Pricing.class]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.scanForAnnotations(AnnotationConfiguration.java:450)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure(WebAppContext.java:517)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1471)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:785)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:502)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner$1.run(Scanner.java:329)
    at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:556)
    at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:506)
Caused by: 
MultiException[java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file Webhook.class, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file Money.class, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file EventList.class, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file CheckoutList.class, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file Addresses.class, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file Checkout.class, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file Pagination.class, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file Event.class, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file Charge.class, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file RequestResponseLoggingInterceptor.class, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file Payment.class, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file ChargeTimeline.class, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file ChargeList.class, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file Pricing.class]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:709)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:709)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:709)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:709)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:850)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:597)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Suppressed: 
    |java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file Money.class
    |   at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:732)
    |   at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:709)
    |   at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:709)
    |   at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:709)
    |   at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:709)
    |   at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:850)
    |   at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:159)
    |   at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:462)
    |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:679)
    |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:597)
    |   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
    |Caused by: 
    |java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    |   at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    |   at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    |   at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    |   at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:979)
    |   at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:725)
    |   at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:709)
    |   at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:709)
    |   at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:709)
    |   at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:709)
    |   at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:850)
    |   at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:159)
    |   at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:462)
    |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:679)
    |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:597)
    |   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Suppressed:
```

mvn dependency:tree :

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ TOOLTANK ---
[INFO] TOOLTANK:TOOLTANK:war:2.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.optimaize.languagedetector:language-detector:jar:0.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.arnx:jsonic:jar:1.2.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.intellij:annotations:jar:12.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:17.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] +- org.languagetool:language-de:jar:4.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.languagetool:languagetool-core:jar:4.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.carrot2:morfologik-fsa:jar:2.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.carrot2:morfologik-fsa-builders:jar:2.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.carrot2:morfologik-speller:jar:2.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.carrot2:morfologik-stemming:jar:2.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.carrotsearch:hppc:jar:0.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.loomchild:segment:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- edu.berkeley.nlp:berkeleylm:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.languagetool:hunspell-native-libs:jar:2.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- de.danielnaber:german-pos-dict:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- edu.washington.cs.knowitall:openregex:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- de.danielnaber:jwordsplitter:jar:4.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.googlecode.lambdaj:lambdaj:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-catalina:jar:7.0.42:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-servlet-api:jar:7.0.42:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:7.0.42:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-annotations-api:jar:7.0.42:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-api:jar:7.0.42:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-util:jar:7.0.42:compile
[INFO] +- com.braintreepayments.gateway:braintree-java:jar:2.74.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.osgi:org.osgi.core:jar:4.2.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.github.seratch:jslack:jar:1.0.12:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:jar:3.8.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.squareup.okio:okio:jar:1.13.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.pdfbox:fontbox:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.odftoolkit:simple-odf:jar:0.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.odftoolkit:odfdom-java:jar:0.8.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queryparser:jar:6.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:jar:6.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-sandbox:jar:6.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:jar:6.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:6.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-suggest:jar:6.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-misc:jar:6.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-backward-codecs:jar:6.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.twelvemonkeys.imageio:imageio-jpeg:jar:3.4-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.twelvemonkeys.imageio:imageio-core:jar:3.4-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.twelvemonkeys.imageio:imageio-metadata:jar:3.4-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.twelvemonkeys.common:common-lang:jar:3.4-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.twelvemonkeys.common:common-io:jar:3.4-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.twelvemonkeys.common:common-image:jar:3.4-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- com.twelvemonkeys.imageio:imageio-tiff:jar:3.4-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-imaging:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.6:compile
[INFO] +- com.github.jai-imageio:jai-imageio-core:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] +- net.sourceforge.tess4j:tess4j:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:4.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.ghost4j:ghost4j:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sourceforge.lept4j:lept4j:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.rococoa:rococoa-core:jar:0.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-svg-dom:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-anim:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-awt-util:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-css:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-dom:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-xml:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-ext:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-parser:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-util:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis-ext:jar:1.3.04:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-codec:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-bridge:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-gvt:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-script:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-js:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-transcoder:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-svggen:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] +- com.cybozu.labs:langdetect:jar:1.1-20120112:compile
[INFO] +- net.gjerull.etherpad:etherpad_lite_client:jar:1.2.12:compile
[INFO] +- cglib:cglib:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- asm:asm:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.velocity:velocity-tools:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-chain:commons-chain:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- sslext:sslext:jar:1.2-0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.struts:struts-core:jar:1.3.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.struts:struts-taglib:jar:1.3.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.struts:struts-tiles:jar:1.3.8:compile
[INFO] +- com.ullink.slack:simpleslackapi:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.5.2:runtime
[INFO] |  \- org.threeten:threetenbp:jar:1.2:runtime
[INFO] +- com.google.gdata:core:jar:1.47.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.docx4j:docx4j:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.plutext:jaxb-svg11:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.plutext:jaxb-xslfo:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.plutext:jaxb-xmldsig-core:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.engio:mbassador:jar:1.1.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:xmlgraphics-commons:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:fop:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-extension:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.avalon.framework:avalon-framework-api:jar:4.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.avalon.framework:avalon-framework-impl:jar:4.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.arnx:wmf2svg:jar:0.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.antlr:stringtemplate:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-csv:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.artofsolving:jodconverter:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.openoffice:juh:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.openoffice:jurt:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.openoffice:ridl:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.openoffice:unoil:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.jxls:jxls:jar:2.2.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-jexl:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.jxls:jxls-poi:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO] +- fr.opensagres.xdocreport:org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core:jar:1.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.poi:ooxml-schemas:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- fr.opensagres.xdocreport:org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.xhtml:jar:1.0.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.15-beta1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.15-beta1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.github.virtuald:curvesapi:jar:1.03:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:jar:3.15-beta1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi-scratchpad:jar:3.15-beta1:compile
[INFO] +- org.swinglabs:pdf-renderer:jar:1.0.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.8.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.jasypt:jasypt:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.jasypt:jasypt-hibernate4:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.mobile:spring-mobile-device:jar:1.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis:jar:1.6.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:4.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl:jar:4.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.evernote:evernote-api:jar:1.25.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.scribe:scribe:jar:1.3.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.mnode.ical4j:ical4j:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.api-client:google-api-client:jar:1.23.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:jar:1.23.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:jar:1.23.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:jar:17.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client:jar:1.19.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:jar:v2-rev332-1.25.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.apis:google-api-services-oauth2:jar:v2-rev141-1.25.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson:jar:1.19.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:jar:1.19.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-java6:jar:1.19.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:jar:6.1.26:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.mortbay.jetty:servlet-api:jar:2.5-20081211:compile
[INFO] +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:jar:6.1.26:provided
[INFO] +- com.google.apis:google-api-services-plus:jar:v1-rev216-1.20.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.dropbox.core:dropbox-core-sdk:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.2.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.9.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.9.Final:compile
[INFO] +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-hikaricp:jar:4.3.9.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.zaxxer:HikariCP-java6:jar:2.3.13:compile
[INFO] +- org.cometd.java:bayeux-api:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.cometd.javascript:cometd-javascript-jquery:war:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.cometd.java:cometd-java-server:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.cometd.java:cometd-java-common:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util-ajax:jar:9.2.22.v20170606:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.2.9.v20150224:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jmx:jar:9.2.9.v20150224:compile
[INFO] +- org.cometd.java:cometd-java-client:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.2.9.v20150224:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.2.9.v20150224:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:jar:9.2.9.v20150224:compile
[INFO] +- org.cometd.java:cometd-java-annotations:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.annotation:jsr250-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.cometd.java:cometd-java-websocket-javax-server:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] +- javax.websocket:javax.websocket-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.cometd.java:cometd-java-websocket-common-server:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.imgscalr:imgscalr-lib:jar:4.2:compile
[INFO] +- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.8.9:compile
[INFO] +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.8.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.itextpdf:itextpdf:jar:5.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:jar:1.38:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:jar:1.38:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.bouncycastle:bctsp-jdk14:jar:1.38:compile
[INFO] +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.0.13:runtime
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.0.13:runtime
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.6.7:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.6.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.6.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.postgresql:postgresql:jar:42.2.5:compile
[INFO] +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.11.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.json:json:jar:20141113:compile
[INFO] +- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.javascript:closure-compiler:jar:v20170806:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.javascript:closure-compiler-externs:jar:v20170806:compile
[INFO] |  +- args4j:args4j:jar:2.33:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.0.18:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.jsinterop:jsinterop-annotations:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] \- nl.geodienstencentrum.maven:sass-maven-plugin:jar:3.5.1:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:3.5.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:3.5.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:3.5.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-settings-builder:jar:3.5.2:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.24:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO]    |  |     \- org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-builder-support:jar:3.5.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:3.5.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:3.5.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:3.5.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-model-builder:jar:3.5.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-resolver-provider:jar:3.5.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-impl:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-api:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-spi:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-util:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-utils:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.eclipse.sisu:org.eclipse.sisu.plexus:jar:0.3.3:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar:1.0-SP4:compile
[INFO]    |  |     \- org.jboss.spec.javax.interceptor:jboss-interceptors-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.0.Beta1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.eclipse.sisu:org.eclipse.sisu.inject:jar:0.3.3:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.google.inject:guice:jar:no_aop:4.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO]    +- org.jruby:jruby-complete:jar:9.1.15.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-logging-api:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO]    |     \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-30:compile
[INFO]    \- org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-impl:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO]       +- org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO]       +- org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-decoration-model:jar:1.7.4:compile
[INFO]       +- org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-core:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO]       |  \- xmlunit:xmlunit:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO]       \- org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-site-renderer:jar:1.7.4:compile
[INFO]          +- org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-skin-model:jar:1.7.4:compile
[INFO]          +- org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-module-xhtml:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO]          +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-i18n:jar:1.0-beta-7:compile
[INFO]          \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-velocity:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Updated cglib and asm, still no luck :

```
 <!-- Apache 2.0 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.10</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
                <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ow2.asm/asm -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
asm:asm:jar:3.3.1:compile
```

That is far too old for Java 10.

You'll need to use asm 7.0 (or newer)

```
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util-ajax:jar:9.2.22.v20170606:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.2.9.v20150224:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jmx:jar:9.2.9.v20150224:compile
[INFO] +- org.cometd.java:cometd-java-client:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.2.9.v20150224:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.2.9.v20150224:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:jar:9.2.9.v20150224:compile
```

Jetty 9.2.9 is too old for Java 9+ support.

Historically, Jetty 9.4.11 was the first to support Java 9 with the ASM 6.2 upgrade.
But the ASM 7.0 upgrade (to support Java 10 and Java 11) introduced an API change in ASM that requires Jetty 9.4.13 or newer.

Comment: Tried your suggestion, didn't help. Please check bottom of main post. Thank you. :-)