# Minimum Jetty version compatible with Java 11

Tags: java, jetty, java-11

What is the minimum jetty version compatible with Java11 ?

I am currently on Jetty6.1.3 that runs on Java7. I tried simply upgrading jre and related dependencies but its not working.

Comment: @Pilpo your information is way out of date with regards to security issues - see https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/security_reports.php

Comment: You are right, I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on what you mean by "compatible with Java11"?

### If you mean "it just works", then use Jetty 9.4.x series.

Being "compatible with Java11" can mean many things, not just the runtime, but also with regards to new features introduced around Java 9 (such as JEP 238, and MultiRelease JAR files).

For Jetty 9.4.x series, the bytecode scanning underwent a few iterations before it was compatible with java 11.

1. on Jetty 9.4.9 the bytecode scanning had to ignore JPMS `module-info.class` content (when run on Java 8 runtime) found in 3rd party jar files at the time.
2. on Jetty 9.4.9 the bytecode scanning had to ignore `META-INF/versions/*` content on Java 8 runtime.
3. on Jetty 9.4.14 the bytecode scanning had to use `META-INF/versions/*` for bytecode scanning on Java 9+ runtime intelligently.
4. on Jetty 9.4.14 the bytecode scanning had to be updated to support the new bytecode format (this means an ASM lib update)

See past answers on these topics

- [Running project with Jetty 9.4.8 (Java 11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67267842/running-project-with-jetty-9-4-8-java-11/67268064#67268064)
- [Spring : Migrating to OpenJDK-10 not working, mvn install is working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54762093/spring-migrating-to-openjdk-10-not-working-mvn-install-is-working)
- [java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry module-info.class from jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52716062/java-lang-runtimeexception-error-scanning-entry-module-info-class-from-jar)
- [Error scanning entry "module-info.class" when starting Jetty server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45311295/error-scanning-entry-module-info-class-when-starting-jetty-server/45362629#45362629)
- [Springboot GCP app engine deployment failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52698333/springboot-gcp-app-engine-deployment-failure/52722120#52722120)
- [Swagger generated JAX-RS server breaks with ElasticSearch dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56381566/swagger-generated-jax-rs-server-breaks-with-elasticsearch-dependency/56383410#56383410)

### If you mean "uses Java 11 effectively", then use Jetty 10.0+

As always, keep your Jetty and JVM up to date. (Especially so if you use SSL/TLS, as things change very fast in that space)

Answer (score 3):

## *Eclipse Jetty*

The [Eclipse Jetty](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/) web site says that both Jetty 10 and 11 are built for Java 11 at a minimum.

| Jetty Version | Servlet API | License | Java |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jetty 9.4.x | 3.1 | JavaEE 8 `javax.servlet.*` | Java 8 |
| Jetty 10.0.x | 4.0 | JavaEE 8 `javax.servlet.*` | Java 11+ |
| Jetty 11.0.x | 5.0 | JakartaEE 9 `jakartaee.servlet.*` | Java 11+ |

Because of the transition from Oracle Corp to the Eclipse Foundation (*Java EE* becoming *Jakarta EE*), and the ensuing change in package names from `javax.*` to `jakarta.*`, the two Jetty versions 10  & 11 are functionally identical. The two versions are developed in parallel. The only significant difference is the package name.

### *Apache Tomcat*

By the way, Apache Tomcat is doing the same, with parallel versions 9 and 10.0, both supporting 8+. They use the *javax* and *jakarta* package naming, respectively.

The next version of **Tomcat, version 10.1.x requires Java 11+**. This next version of Tomcat will support the next versions of [Jakarta 10](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jakartaee-platform/jakartaee10/JakartaEE10) technologies still under development, such as [Servlet 6](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ee4j.servlet/releases/6.0). See the [*Which version?*](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) page on Tomcat site.

## Upgrade to Jetty 10 on Java 11

You may be able to do a direct upgrade by going to Jetty 10 on Java 11.